# Fixed number of color on Chromatic Circle with cv2

Tags: python, opencv, hsv, bgr

I'm trying to get a set of a specific number of colors covering all the chromatic circles using cv2.

I'm actually using this function :

```
hue_values = np.linspace(0, 360, nbr_max_people)
        for hue in hue_values:
            color = np.array([hue, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)  
            color_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[color]], dtype=np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)[0][0]
            print(color_rgb)
            self.colors.append(tuple(map(int, color_rgb)))
```

It's working for the first 5 colors and then it go back to the beginning of the circle (ie. red) and get random others colors.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html

Comment: Hint: an 8 bit unsigned integer cannot represent values higher than 255. (That's why the range of hue used by OpenCV in this case is 0..179, as the documentation explains).